# Replace ID with Name in MVC

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I have this structure:

```
public struct IdandName
    {
        public IdandName(string id, string name)
        {
            s_ID = id;
            s_Name = name;
        }
        public string s_ID { get; }
        public string s_Name { get; }
    };
```

for example, there is a `IdandName` list, I want to show the `s_Name` variable on my site and return `s_ID` in my drop down list. How should I do it? I assigned all the `s_ID` from the example list to `ViewBag.id` so it can be shown on the site.

this is my view:

````
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.id, new SelectList(ViewBag.id) )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>```
````

Answer (score 1):

System.Web.Mvc offers a class named `SelectListItem` that can be used with `DropDownListFor()`. You can still use it with your custom type like this :
I assume that your items contains 'jobs' for the example

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly List<IdandValue> jobs;
    
    [Display(Name = "Job")]
    public int SelectedJobId { get; set; }
 
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> JobItems
        => new SelectList(jobs, "s_ID", "s_Name");
    // or
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> JobItems
        => jobs.Select(j => new SelectListItem { Value = j.s_ID, Text = j.s_Name });
}
```

you can call it like this in your view

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.SelectedJobId) // just showing the DisplayAttribute.Name "Job"
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedJobId, Model.JobItems)
```

You can make a custom extension method for DropDownListFor Handling this kind of items but i think you can do it with this.

Note : remember C# naming convention is **PascalCase** or **camelCase** so prefer use "Id" instead of "s_ID" and "Name" instead of "s_Name"